# When button is pressed wait 3 seconds then submit javascript

Tags: javascript

How do i make a Javascript that will make so when i press my submit button it will change the name of the button to something like this "Loading..." and after 3 sec the button should be pressed

```
<input type="Submit" name="submitNew" id="submitNew" value="Send">
```

It will act as an "spam filter" for humans..

Comment: That's not a great way to prevent spam...

Comment: Define "spam filter". If you are worrying about bots this will fail, because they will not have JS enabled in most cases.

Comment: You have to use a timer http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp the on mouse down will put a flag somewhere and start the timer, on mouse up will remove this flag and stop the timer. If once the timer is fired the flag is present, then you know that you pressed the mouse all the time long.

Answer (score 7):

One possible solution is to set `submit` event for `form` element in the following way:

*HTML:*

```
<form onsubmit="return formSubmit(this);">
```

*JavaScript:*

```
function formSubmit(form) {
    document.getElementById("submitNew").value = "Loading...";
    setTimeout(function() {
        form.submit();
    }, 3000);  // 3 seconds
    return false;
}
```

Another way is to set the event dynamically (*tribute to the kittens!*):

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("formID").onsubmit = function() {
        var form = this;
        document.getElementById("submitNew").value = "Loading...";
        setTimeout(function() {
            form.submit();
        }, 3000); // 3 seconds
        return false;
    };
};​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/spWDk/

Comment: Do you have to use that inline JavaScript? Think of the kittens.

Comment: Where should i put that html?

Comment: @user1867369 Check the DEMO from the updated answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: @PeeHaa Especially for the kittens :)

Comment: Thanks that worke, heh just an addon how can i make so the dots in "Loading..." are like this,     "Loading."  "Loading.." "Loading..." so it looks like its loading with the dots.

Comment: @user1867369 Though it's a different question, the very basic implementation could be as in here: http://jsfiddle.net/spWDk/1/.

Comment: Thanks for thinking about the kittens :) One last nitpicking thing: it would even be better to use an `eventListener` or you may get hit by an override of `window.onload` somewhere in your code.

Comment: @PeeHaa Think of the IE users. Too many compatibility issues should be targeted in the answer then. Here `window.onload` was used as an example of DOM ready importance.

Comment: @VisioN Actually it isn't that hard to make IE behave in this case: `var type = 'submit'; if (window.addEventListener) { document.addEventListener(type, callback); } else { document.attachEvent('on' + type, callback); }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below solution:

```
<form action="https://google.com" method="post" name="simulation" id="simulation">
    <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom"/>
    <input type="text" name="prenom" id="prenom"/>
    <input type="submit" value"Submit">
</form>
<script>
$("#simulation").on('submit', function (e) {
    console.log("Submitted");
    //stop form submission
    e.preventDefault();
    //Do your custom work.
    setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('simulation').submit(); }, 5000);
});
</script>
```